# Storing ls output in a variable and splitting it is not working

Tags: bash, sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

dirs="$(ls /)"
IFS=' ' read -a dir <<<"$dirs"
for item in "${dir[@]}"; do
    if [[ $item != "proc" ]]; then
        du -sh /$item
    fi
done
```

I want to list the folders in /, and checked the size of them, `ls /` response `bin boot dev etc home lib lib64 media mnt opt proc root run sbin srv sys tmp usr var`, but the result is only one item `0       /bin`, if I change to to

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

dirs="bin boot dev etc home lib lib64 media mnt opt proc root run sbin srv sys tmp usr var"
IFS=' ' read -a dir <<<"$dirs"
for item in "${dir[@]}"; do
    if [[ $item != "proc" ]]; then
        du -sh /$item
    fi
done
```

the result will be correct, how to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

This has been mentioned in several posts multiple times. Don't use the output of `ls` programmatically. It has serveral pitfalls. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

All you need is the glob expansion provided by the shell itself to list the directories under the `/` directory. Also you *shouldn't* use variables to store multi word content. You *need* to use arrays!

```
shopt -s nullglob
topDirs=(/*/)
```

Now the `topDirs` array will contain all the folder names under the root directory, which you can use a loop to parse,

```
for dir in "${topDirs[@]}"; do
    if [[ $dir != "/proc/" ]]; then
        du -sh "$dir"
    fi
done
```

---

As far why your code didn't work, doing `ls /` is not a valid glob expansion to list directories, it lists *both* files and directories. Also the output of `ls` is newline separated. The variable `dirs` will have the contents separated by new line, so your logic to split on `IFS=' '` would *never* work. It will just store the first line in your list returned. You should have used `mapfile` or `readarray` to read in newline separated list of entries

```
mapfile -t dir <<<"$dirs"
```

But the entire logic is in question, because `ls` splits file names if it contains spaces or other special characters. So better to avoid this and do the glob expansion logic as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Your `IFS` line is unneeded. If you are sure there are no directories with spaces (as evident from your `IFS` line) you can use:

```
dirs="$(ls /)"
for item in $dirs; do
    if [[ $item != "proc" ]]; then
        du -sh /$item
    fi
done
```

Note you can omit the `[@]` as well, the loop will iterate on words (hence spaces in folders will break this). Better yet:

```
for item in /*/; do
    if [[ $item != "proc" ]]; then
        du -sh "$item"
    fi
done
```

will also handle directories with spaces.

Comment: it won't work it's like execute `du -sh /bin boot dev etc home lib lib64 media mnt opt proc root run sbin srv sys tmp usr var`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing difficult something a lot simpler:

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -type d -a ! -path / -a ! -path /proc | xargs du -sh
```

With `find` you capture all the folders at that level excluding at the same time `/` and `/proc`, finally you used `xargs` to pass the folder list to `du` in order to compute the sizes.

Comment: thanks for the information, but I am learning shell script, try to practice

Comment: by the way, the command is not correct, because it shows the total size of the / folder just like du -sh /

Comment: ??? It show the same than your script: `du -sh /$item`. In fact, my script (thanks to xargs) is equivalent to `du -sh /bin /boot /dev /etc /home /lib /lib64 /media /mnt /opt /root /run /sbin /srv /sys /tmp /usr /var`

Comment: Oh! I see... you are half right. The output of find includes `/`. Let me edit the answer and correct that.

Comment: may I ask what -a for, the result looks like the same if I don't have it

Comment: Logical and. Two expressions in a row are taken to be joined with an implied "and". "-a" is the same, just I made it explicit. You also have "-o", the logical or. These are short-circuit evaluations: if first expression of an "and" evaluates to false, the second check is not done (and equivalently for the "or").

Comment: @Poshi/Chan: While this answer is good, using `find`/`xargs` is not needed for such a simple task. You can use the shell glob expansions itself.

Comment: @Poshi you mean -a and -o is not from `find` command, it could use anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

try
`mapfile -t dirs <<<"$(ls /)"` it must gives you a result without splitting by spaces